# Copy from Google Cloud Storage Bucket to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have set up an airflow workflow that ingests some files from s3 to Google Cloud storage and then runs a workflow of sql queries to create new tables on Big Query. At the end of the workflow I need to push the output of the one final Big Query table to Google Cloud Storage and from there to S3.

I have cracked the the transfer of the Big Query table to Google Cloud Storage with no issues using the `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` python operator. However it seems the transfer from Google Cloud Storage to S3 is a less trodden route and I have been unable to find a solution which I can automate in my Airflow workflow.

I am aware of `rsync` which comes as part of the `gsutil` and have gotten this working (see post [Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3)) but I am unable to add this into my workflow.

I have a dockerised airflow container running on a compute engine instance.

Would really appreciate help solving this problem.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So we are also using `rsync` to move data between S3 and GCS,

You first need to get a bash script working, something like `gsutil -m rsync -d -r gs://bucket/key s3://bucket/key`

For s3 you also need to provide `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as environment variable.

Then define your BashOperator and put it in your DAG file

```
rsync_yesterday = BashOperator(task_id='rsync_task_' + table,
                                bash_command='Your rsync script',
                                dag=dag)
```

Comment: thanks Chengzhi - how do you define the S3 creds on compute engine? Locally on my mac I have added them to the .boto config file but I am unable to find its equivalent on my compute engine instance.

Comment: Can you try to ssh and add the .boto config file on compute engine?

Comment: I have spun up a Hadoop cluster using DataProc and done the transfer using `distcp`. I will update answer once I have the airflow `DataProcHadoopOperator` working.

Comment: you could also use the export command for the credentials in the bash command. bash_command='export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="your_key"; export  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="your_secret"; gsutil -m rsync -d -r gs://bucket/key s3://bucket/key'

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to copy objects from GC storage bucket to S3 using AWS Lambda.

**Python boto3 library** allows *listing and downloading* objects from GC bucket.

Below is sample lambda code to copy "sample-data-s3.csv" object from GC bucket to s3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import io

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

google_access_key_id="GOOG1EIxxMYKEYxxMQ"
google_access_key_secret="QifDxxMYSECRETKEYxxVU1oad1b"

gc_bucket_name="my_gc_bucket"


def get_gcs_objects(google_access_key_id, google_access_key_secret,
                     gc_bucket_name):
    """Gets GCS objects using boto3 SDK"""
    client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="auto",
                          endpoint_url="https://storage.googleapis.com",
                          aws_access_key_id=google_access_key_id,
                          aws_secret_access_key=google_access_key_secret)

    # Call GCS to list objects in gc_bucket_name
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket=gc_bucket_name)

    # Print object names
    print("Objects:")
    for blob in response["Contents"]:
        print(blob)    

    object = s3.Object('my_aws_s3_bucket', 'sample-data-s3.csv')
    f = io.BytesIO()
    client.download_fileobj(gc_bucket_name,"sample-data.csv",f)
    object.put(Body=f.getvalue())

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    get_gcs_objects(google_access_key_id,google_access_key_secret,gc_bucket_name)
```

You can loop through `blob` to download all objects from GC bucket.

Hope this helps someone who wants to use AWS lambda to transfer objects from GC bucket to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest overall option is [gsutil rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync), however there are scenarios where rsync might take too many resources or won't be fast enough.

Couple other alternatives:

- Look into Amazon's equivalent of Data Transfer Service, called [Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) that will allow you to import data from GCS to S3
- Use [Hadoop DistCp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) with DataProc to parallelize the copying process ([see example](https://medium.com/swlh/transfer-data-from-gcs-to-s3-using-google-dataproc-with-airflow-aa49dc896dad))

Answer (score -1):

Google recommends using it's `transfer service` for transfers between cloud platforms. You can programatically setup a transfer using their python API. This way the data is transferred directly between S3 and google cloud storage. The disadvantage of using `gsutil` and `rsync` is that the data will have to go through the machine/instance which executes the `rsync` command. This can be a bottle neck.

[Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service Doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-program)

Comment: I don't think that transfer service supports GCS to S3, only S3 to GCS. I could be mistaken though

Comment: you are correct. According to this google transfer service documentation there is only a gcs sink. https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec