# How to transfer data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3 and get the associated cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I noticed that Google Cloud's Storage Transfer Service only works when the sink bucket is Google Cloud, not S3. However, I would like to move files from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3, and an alternative I can think of is to spin up an instance on Google Cloud, install the AWS CLI, and then transfer the files that way.

My questions are:

1) Is there a better approach than that?

2) If I did the transfer via the instance, is there a clear way of getting the cost for doing that?

Comment: See also: [Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333278/174777)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at using Amazon's data transfer service?

[Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html)

If you're looking at transferring data outside of Google's Network you'll be subject to egress charges. You can get an estimate of prices here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMcC. I think Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration doesn't operate with Google though.