# Rails Active Storage - How to migrate local files to s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

Earlier my files were uploading in the storage folder. But now I want to upload images on the s3 bucket. how can I migrate my existing local data on the s3 bucket?

I found the script here https://www.stefanwienert.de/blog/2018/11/05/active-storage-migrate-between-providers-from-local-to-amazon/
But getting an error of

> NoMethodError (private method `open' called for Active Storage

So what should I do for migrating my local data to the s3 bucket?

Is there in a simpler way?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer from Dorian I constructed a simpler version. For this version you don't need to select your classes or know/care how the method inside the class is called.

It *should* also work for `has_many_attached` (since we start from the attachment itself)

Just like with Dorian's version, you need to add your config for s3 before this and have this deployed

```rb
ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_each do |at|
  next unless at.blob.service_name == "local"
  begin
    blob = at.blob
    blob.open do |f|
      at.record.send(at.name).attach(io: f, content_type: blob.content_type, filename: blob.filename)
    end
    blob.destroy
  rescue ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError
    # Add some message or warning here if you fancy
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks RobbeVP, it works to me! Only got the exception `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey` with `blob.destroy`. I fix it by adding another rake task to delete the old attachments: `ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_each {|at| at.purge if at.blob.service_name == "local"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also got that error and I have changed the script to rake task like below:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

namespace :active_storage do
  desc 'Migrate ActiveStorage files from local to Amazon S3'
  task migrate: :environment do
    module ActiveStorage
      class Downloader
        def initialize(blob, tempdir: nil)
          @blob    = blob
          @tempdir = tempdir
        end

        def download_blob_to_tempfile
          open_tempfile do |file|
            download_blob_to file
            verify_integrity_of file
            yield file
          end
        end

        private

        attr_reader :blob, :tempdir

        def open_tempfile
          file = Tempfile.open(["ActiveStorage-#{blob.id}-", blob.filename.extension_with_delimiter], tempdir)

          begin
            yield file
          ensure
            file.close!
          end
        end

        def download_blob_to(file)
          file.binmode
          blob.download { |chunk| file.write(chunk) }
          file.flush
          file.rewind
        end

        def verify_integrity_of(file)
          raise ActiveStorage::IntegrityError unless Digest::MD5.file(file).base64digest == blob.checksum
        end
      end
    end

    module AsDownloadPatch
      def open(tempdir: nil, &block)
        ActiveStorage::Downloader.new(self, tempdir: tempdir).download_blob_to_tempfile(&block)
      end
    end

    Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
      ActiveStorage::Blob.send(:include, AsDownloadPatch)
    end

    def migrate(from, to)
      configs = Rails.configuration.active_storage.service_configurations
      from_service = ActiveStorage::Service.configure from, configs
      to_service   = ActiveStorage::Service.configure to, configs

      ActiveStorage::Blob.service = from_service

      puts "#{ActiveStorage::Blob.count} Blobs to go..."
      ActiveStorage::Blob.find_each do |blob|
        print '.'
        file = Tempfile.new("file#{Time.now}")
        file.binmode
        file << blob.download
        file.rewind
        checksum = blob.checksum
        to_service.upload(blob.key, file, checksum: checksum)
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
        puts 'Rescued by Errno::ENOENT statement.'
        next
      end
    end

    migrate(:local, :s3)
  end
end
```

Comment: i will check it out later.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way that works:

- add an `amazon` section to your `config/storage.yml`

like

- change your storage service to `:amazon` in your `config/environments/production.rb`
- add this rake task as `lib/tasks/storage.rake`

```
namespace :storage do
  task reupload: :environment do
    [User, Event].each do |clazz|
      collection = clazz.with_attached_image

      puts "#{clazz} has #{collection.count} images"

      collection.find_each do |user|
        next unless user.image.blob
        user
          .image
          .blob
          .open do |f|
            user.image.attach(io: f, filename: user.image.blob.filename)
          end

        print "."
      end

      puts
    end
  end
end
```

- run and test locally to try it with `rake storage:reupload` (and changing to `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` in `config/environments/development.rb`)
- check that everything works fine locally (your images should link to your AWS URLs)
- upload to your server (`cap deploy` for instance)
- run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake storage:reupload` in the directory of your project
- wait for a bit, depending on how many images you are reuploading
- Profit! Enjoy! Party time!

**Pros**

- don't do any monkey patching
- doesn't rely on rails internals, e.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/41636
- simple code

**Cons**

- Didn't make it work for `has_many_attached` but shouldn't be too many changes
- You have to select your models
- It assumes it's all named `image` (nothing too hard to fix)

Comment: a quick fix would be to do `send(:open)` instead of `open`

Comment: the task file name should be: `lib/tasks/storage.rake`

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :active_storage do
  desc 'Migrate ActiveStorage files from local to minio'
  task migrate: :environment do
    module ActiveStorage
      class Downloader
        def initialize(blob, tempdir: nil)
          @blob    = blob
          @tempdir = tempdir
        end

        def download_blob_to_tempfile
          open_tempfile do |file|
            download_blob_to file
            verify_integrity_of file
            yield file
          end
        end

        private

        attr_reader :blob, :tempdir

        def open_tempfile
          file = Tempfile.open(["ActiveStorage-#{blob.id}-", blob.filename.extension_with_delimiter], tempdir)

          begin
            yield file
          ensure
            file.close!
          end
        end

        def download_blob_to(file)
          file.binmode
          blob.download { |chunk| file.write(chunk) }
          file.flush
          file.rewind
        end

        def verify_integrity_of(file)
          raise ActiveStorage::IntegrityError unless Digest::MD5.file(file).base64digest == blob.checksum
        end
      end
    end

    module AsDownloadPatch
      def open(tempdir: nil, &block)
        ActiveStorage::Downloader.new(self, tempdir: tempdir).download_blob_to_tempfile(&block)
      end
    end

    Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
      ActiveStorage::Blob.send(:include, AsDownloadPatch)
    end

    def migrate(from, to)
        config_file = Rails.root.join("config/storage.yml")
      configs = ActiveSupport::ConfigurationFile.parse(config_file)
      from_service = ActiveStorage::Service.configure from, configs
      to_service   = ActiveStorage::Service.configure to, configs

      ActiveStorage::Blob.service = from_service

      puts "#{ActiveStorage::Blob.count} Blobs to go..."
      ActiveStorage::Blob.find_each do |blob|
        print '.'
        file = Tempfile.new("file#{Time.now}")
        file.binmode
        file << blob.download
        file.rewind
        checksum = blob.checksum
        to_service.upload(blob.key, file, checksum: checksum)
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
        puts 'Rescued by Errno::ENOENT statement.'
        next
      end
    end

    migrate(:local, :minio)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to migrate your local files to s3-service is:

— setup as mirror it first,

— sync all mirrors with rake,

— remove mirror setup,

— remove local files after check

I guess this solution will help:
[How to sync new ActiveStorage mirrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684443/how-to-sync-new-activestorage-mirrors)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of RobbeVP, I make it work with the following tasks:

```
namespace :active_storage do
  task reupload_to_s3: :environment do
    raise "Please switch the active storage service to 'amazon' first" if ENV['ACTIVE_STORAGE_SERVICE'] != 'amazon'
    ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_each do |at|
      next unless at.blob.service_name == "local"
      begin
        blob = at.blob
        blob.open do |f|
          at.record.send(at.name).attach(io: f, content_type: blob.content_type, filename: blob.filename)
        end
      rescue ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError
        puts "FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::Attachment##{at.id}"
      end
    end
  end

  task delete_local_attachments: :environment do
    ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_each do |at|
      next unless at.blob.service_name == "local"
      at.purge
    end
  end
end
```