# Want to change my config.active_storage.service but keep or migrate my existing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

So I didn't realize that I had been saving files and images in production to
`config.active_storage.service = :local`

I want it to match my staging which is
`config.active_storage.service = :digitalocean_spaces`

The problem is when I switch it I break all the links to the old images. Question is how do I migrate those files into my digitalocean_spaces or even get them out of active_storage.serivce local to upload them into my digital oceans space

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [Mirror Service](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#mirror-service):

> You can keep multiple services in sync by defining a mirror service. A
> mirror service replicates uploads and deletes across two or more
> subordinate services.
>
> A mirror service is intended to be used temporarily during a migration
> between services in production. You can start mirroring to a new
> service, copy pre-existing files from the old service to the new, then
> go all-in on the new service.

You'll also need a custom script to sync your files between the mirrors. Basically, you have to call `mirror_later` on each blob (works on Rails 6.1+):

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.all.each do |blob|
  blob.mirror_later
end
```

Read more examples and approaches in the following answer: [How to sync new ActiveStorage mirrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684443/how-to-sync-new-activestorage-mirrors)