# Moving data from google cloud storage to Amazon s3 via cloud function in a serverless fashion

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have data in Google Cloud Storage that I need to transfer to s3 bucket in a serverless fashion...
one possible approach is to use cloud function and transmit data from cloud storage to s3 bucket using gsutil and boto3 for was credentials. I believe their is an extra fee from Google for outbound network request but this approach is possible.

Does anyone has a better approach or a suggestion?

Comment: Is it necessary the serverless function? I mean, there is already a simple approach defined [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333278/3058302)

Comment: Yup, ideally we would like to go serverless. I have seen many options (inc. the one that you pointed to) that include a server but serverless makes it little tricky. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no better than `gsutil`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333278/10801700

Did you consider the [Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) in your evaluation? There is "1 GB from North America to each GCP egress destination (Australia and China excluded)" each month. Once you've passed this limit, the [general network usage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress) applies.

Note that for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits): "Always Free is only available in **us-east1**, **us-west1**, and **us-central1** regions. Usage calculations are combined across those regions."

Comment: Found a way : Using boto3 and google cloud storage as requirements, I was able to write a google cloud function, which basically triggered on landing a file in GCS, read the file in memory and passed it over into s3 bucket. A 150MB file took less than 30 sec.

Comment: @Karan could you share the snippet?

Comment: Lol right. I agree, please share