# Migrating data from Google Cloud Platform to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-transfer

I tried to migrate data from Google Cloud Platform, I tried this method by Mike [Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3/39333278#39333278), but got the complaint, anyone knows what should I do next?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your internet connection is stable, this happens when you don't have a stable network and as a result it will return a broken pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you're using `gsutil rsync` method, the transferred data will actually go through the machine you run the command from. If it has a poor or unstable internet connection you may face this kind of issues.

To avoid it, one option is to create a Compute Engine VM in your Google Cloud project and run the `gsutil rsync` command in there, so you can take advantage of Google network. Once the transfer is finished you can delete the VM.

Another option is to use [Google Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview).

Comment: Note for anyone looking for GCS to S3 transfers. The Transfer Service only writes to GCS destinations.