# Using gsutil to rsync from GCP to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, rsync, gsutil

There's a similar question with answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3). However, the top answer there does not work for me:

If I use:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://your-gcs-bucket s3://your-s3-bucket
```

It fails for me with:

```
The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-2'
```

Ok, rclone does work but, still, why not with gsutil rync?

I'm in London region by the way.

Comment: One possible clue might be this article in AWS which describes some reasons and fixes ... does any of this sound applicable to your story?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-400-bad-request.html

Comment: I'm familiar to that and in almost all commands involved in GCP or AWS there is an option for `--region` or `--zone`. In this particular case, which is more complicated, I want to set the region for AWS within a call from a GCP command. I've tried using ENV set up or default setup with GCP and AWS but for no avail so far. I wish I could understand hor `rclone` is sorting this issue.

Comment: Just a wild guess ... maybe edit ~/.boto   I'm sesnsing a couple of possibilities ... either host=s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com under an s3 section or https_validate_certificates = false under the Boto section.

Comment: Thanks for your tip @Kolban, indeed, editing `~/.boto` and adding under `[Credentials]` `s3_host = s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` did solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associated with the gsutil command is a configuration file called `~/.boto`.  Within this file one can add/code:

```
[Credentials]
s3_host=s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

For details on this file and related information, please see:

[config - Obtain credentials and create configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config)