# Specify S3-compatible endpoint in GCS Transfer

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, transfer

I'm setting up a storage bucket transfer from GC to an external S3-compatible service (Digital Ocean), as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/s3-compatible). Everything seems to be ready (i.e., pool, active agent, and a transfer job calculating size for almost 2 hours!?), but I am curious about the `endpoint` used as a sink by the agent installed using the default process specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/transfer/agents/install).

Both the documentation listed here talk about how to specify the KEY and SECRET, but not the endpoint. What is it? Why can't I clearly say where (endpoint) a data transfer should go, as I do for the KEY and SECRET? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Investigating other transfer options I've found the `gsutil` approach (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005171/) which led me to learn about the `.boto` configuration file (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil), which has the `s3_host` option. It has worked using `gsutil`, so I imagine that something similar needs to be added to the GSC Transfer agent.

Comment: mentioned in this [document](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/spaces-api/#:~:text=endpoint%3A%20'https%3A%2F%2Fnyc3.,the%20control%20panel%2C%20under%20Settings.) you can find your endpoint in the control panel, under Settings

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint needs to be provided when creating an actual transfer job using an agent for which you specified the KEY and SECRET.