# Why this sudden error "No URLS matched" when transferring data from a Google cloud bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-data-transfer

My data transfer from a google cloud bucket to AWS bucket was in progress but after a few hours I go this error - "

- Command exception : NO URLs MATCHED"

please see the screenshot here.. Any idea why this error and how I can resolve it?

[image]

Comment: as a quick check run this " gsutil ls "command to list the buckets and check weather the bucket your using in the "gsutil cp " is there or not.

did you activate the AWS credential ?

Comment: @Sri, yes the credentials were activated... the transfer was in progress and after 10 GB or so, it threw this message, cant understand why.....

Comment: What is Size of the data your trying to transfer ? Have you tried to transfer small file ( eg. 1mb ), If not can you try it. Please let me know the outcome.

Comment: @Sri, its about 4 TB in total....we have transferred 10GB so far ...and midway this happened..it threw this command exception ......How can we solve this?any  idea

Comment: Can you try using -R instead of -r. Kindly let me know the outcome.

Comment: @Sri even that doesnt work.... we are still left scratching our heads!

Comment: @Standford As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migration-to-google-cloud-transferring-your-large-datasets) ```gsutil``` is recommended if the data is less than 1TB. Please look at the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Stuck in the same boat!

Answer (score 1):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migration-to-google-cloud-transferring-your-large-datasets) gsutil is recommended if the data is less than 1TB. Please look at the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3)